# Why am I getting a linker error when I use an Irvine32 function?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to run an assembly program using MASM in Visual Studio. This is the code I have

```
include Irvine32.inc

.data
str1 BYTE "a test string",0

.code
main proc
    mov edx,OFFSET str1
    call WriteString
    exit
main endp
End main
```

The error I'm getting is:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WriteString@0 referenced in function _main@0"

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you linking against `Irvine32.lib`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah I figured out I didn't add that in the Solution's properties. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

- Press `Shift + Alt + A`
- find *Irvine32.inc* and *Irvine32.lib* from your HDD
- *Add* them in your project repository.

Answer (score 0):

The linker error suggests that you aren't linking against the *Irvine32* library. Although you have included `Irvine32.inc` at the top of your assembly program, you still need to add `Irvine32.lib` as a library to link against in your Solution, or add it to your command line (if compiling with at a command shell), or use `includelib` directive inside your assembly code to link with it.